# How do I design a database schema for a chat application with mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, schema

I am trying to design the database schema for a simple chat application with MongoDB. The requirements are simple.

1. Users can send messages to "friends" (existing contacts) and "strangers" in real time.
2. Users can load the history of their conversation.
3. Users can delete their own conversations in their inbox without deleting conversations in other users' inboxes.
4. When the user chats with a new friend, the new friend should be added to the user's contact list.
5. If a user is offline while a message comes in, it should be marked as unread.

I have come up with simple schemas myself, as follows: I'd really appreciate it if anyone could give me some ideas on how I can make this more performance-friendly.

```
interface Inbox {
     uid: string,
     userId: string,
     participants: Participants[]
}

interface Participant{
    uid: string,
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    avatar: string,
    email: string,
    created_at: string,
    inbox_id: string
}

interface Message {
   uid: string,
   from: string,
   to: string,
   msg_type: strig,
   file_url: string,
   text: string,
   seen: string    
}
```

Each **Inbox** is associated with one user, and two participants in a conversation are created as two **participants** stored separately in inboxes. **Messages** are in a different table and are fetched based on the inbox owner and conversation participant.

The problem so far is that there is a lot of updating of fields for both parties to a conversation while sending and fetching messages.

Any suggestions on how I can make this more performance-friendly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are all conversations only consisting of 2 participants? If you are not planning to implement a group conversation, it seems to me that you don't need the Inbox schema. The user schema can have a list of IDs of users, that the given user has a conversation with. If the `Participant` is equivalent to the "user" of your application, its schema can look like this:

```
interface Participant{
    uid: string,
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    avatar: string,
    email: string,
    created_at: string,
    inbox_id: string,
    conversation_user_ids: string[] // This will be an array of userIds
}
```

When a user deletes a conversation with somebody, you only remove the given userId from their conversation_user_ids. The array of userIds for the other user remains unchanged.

However, if you plan to implement a group conversation, I think the Inbox schema is useful. I would still include it in the Participant schema though and remove `Participants` from it, e.g. reversing the dependency.